# Display an image over the screen

Tags: image

I have a map that is 40x50 that shows when the visitor comes to the website, i would like the visitor to click the map which puts in topmost actual size 400x500 and everything beneath is blacked out, when they click off the pic it will simply vanish.

I have seem it happen in many galleries but can't seem to find one i can recode and don't even know what the actual process of doing this is called.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the word you're looking for is lightbox.

See this: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

By the way, tags are for tagging what languages you are using. Appropriate tags for this post would probably be html and javascript. The image tag is alright, but without context, it's difficult to figure out how your are trying to implement it.

Comment: yes like that, but i need the image to be actual size and not fit to screen